# Recursion showing error for finding longest common sub-sequence in python

Tags: python, debugging, recursion, lcs

This is the [ideone link](https://pastebin.com/i3T1x8zk). I want to solve the famous lcs problem by dynamic programming, but can't figure this error out. It says as following when I run this function:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

```
a = "ABCBDABA"
b = "BDCABAD"
d = dict()
def lcs(m, n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    key = str(m) + "|" + str(n)
    if key not in d.keys():
        #print(key)           
        if a[m - 1] == b[n - 1]:
            d[key] = lcs(m - 1, n - 1) + 1
        else:
            d[key] = max(lcs(m - 1, n), lcs(m, n - 1))
    else:
        return d[key]

lcs(len(a), len(b))
print(d)
```

Comment: I did not go through the whole logic, but in your second if-statement, you are not returning anything, which returns None. You probably want the return d[key] at the end to be unconditional

Comment: Why use `if key not in d.keys()`?  A major point of a `dict` is that you can test for membership directly:  `if key not in d`

Comment: Thanks.... I'll keep that in mind for the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What line is the error occurring on?  I'm guessing that it's the line

```py
d[key] = lcs(m - 1, n - 1) + 1
```

because the error is saying that you're adding two objects, one of type `int` and one that has no specified type (which Python calls `NoneType`).  This means that your `lcs` function is not returning anything when you give it the inputs `m - 1` and `n - 1`.  This is happening because the only `return` statement in your function occurs in the outermost `else` condition.

That is to say, you need your function to return something, an integer perhaps, when the key `str(m) + "|" + str(n)` is not in the dictionary.

I don't know if this is the output you're looking for, but I added a return statement:

```py
a = "ABCBDABA"
b = "BDCABAD"
d = dict()
def lcs(m, n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    key = str(m) + "|" + str(n)
    if key not in d.keys():
        #print(key)           
        if a[m - 1] == b[n - 1]:
            d[key] = lcs(m - 1, n - 1) + 1
        else:
            d[key] = max(lcs(m - 1, n), lcs(m, n - 1))
        return d[key]
    else:
        return d[key]

lcs(len(a), len(b))
print(d)
```

and now the above code, when run, returns:

```
{'1|6': 1, '1|4': 1, '2|5': 2, '2|6': 2, '1|1': 0, '1|2': 0, '1|3': 0, '2|1': 1, '2|2': 1, '2|3': 1, '2|4': 1, '3|3': 2, '3|4': 2, '3|5': 2, '3|6': 2, '4|5': 3, '4|6': 3, '5|7': 4, '3|1': 1, '3|2': 1, '4|1': 1, '4|2': 1, '4|3': 2, '4|4': 2, '5|2': 2, '5|3': 2, '5|4': 2, '5|5': 3, '6|6': 4, '6|7': 4, '6|4': 3, '7|5': 4, '7|6': 4, '7|7': 4, '8|6': 5, '8|7': 5}
```

Comment: I was just trying to learn and implement this.... https://www.techiedelight.com/longest-common-subsequence/